# Update post_meta post_name with the post ID from wp_insert_post after user register

Tags: wp-insert-post, save-post, post-meta, user-registration

I'm creating a function that creates a page for a user when they register. The post created sits within a certain category. These are standard posts NOT custom post types.

After the post is created I want to grab the ID and overwrite the post_name with it.

I have this so far, create the post:

```
function add_memberzone_page( $user_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post', true, $user_id );
    if( $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where' ) >= 1 ) return;

    $user_page = array(
        'post_title' => $user->first_name,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_excerpt' => '',
        'post_category' => '21',
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    wp_insert_post( $user_page );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_memberzone_page', 999 );
```

update the post:

```
function update_memberzone_page( $post_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_page );

    $post_update = array(
        'post_name' => $post_id,
    );

    update_post_meta( $post_update );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_memberzone_page', 10, 3 );
```

Any help with pushing me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the two functions/hooks - just use the first, with the addition of:

```
if ( $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_page ) ) {
    wp_update_post(
        array(
            'ID'        => $post_id,
            'post_name' => $post_id,
        )
    );
}
```